# How to find all folders and files that have Chinese characters using Perl's File::Find?

Tags: perl

I am new to File::Find and I want to search folders and files from particular folder. I tried to search folders, but it missed some folders and files, because these folder names have Chinese characters.

How can I read these folders using File::Find?

Folder name and file name:

```
引爆点——如何引发流行（新版）
    引爆点——如何引发流行（新版）.txt
```

I tried:

```
use strict;
use File::Find;
find({ wanted => \&processFile,}, '.');
sub processFile{
        print $File::Find::name, "\n";
}
```

Output is nothing and no errors and warnings,
how to read this folders and files....?

Comment: @serenesat, thanks now changed that one...

Comment: What is the encoding of your directory and file names? Does your code work for english file and directory names?

Comment: I created your example file and folder by copy/pasting from the question and ran your code. It finds them along with everything else. That's on Perl 5.20.1 and Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Are you running it in the right directoy?

Comment: Ya, I running current directory... ex: "."

Comment: Works for me as well (on perl 5.18 / Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: @neuhaus, I will try this version and with windows

Comment: The `.` doesn't mean you are in the same directory as the folder you want. It means you are using the current working directory. Use [Cwd(https://metacpan.org/pod/Cwd)]'s `cwd()` function to print your working directory. Maybe you are running from the wrong place.

Comment: No no, English text only read, Chinese language not read....